# ThinkingSphinx not accepting conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm having trouble getting ThinkingSphinx to recognize my conditions.

My Discussion model includes the following code:

```
define_index do
  indexes [subject, body], :as => :text
  indexes replies.body, :as => :reply_text
  set_property :delta => true
end
```

And as expected this search

```
Discussion.search "handy"
```

returns any discussion with the word "handy" in its subject, body, or the body of one of its replies.

Now I'm implementing a "deleting posts" feature, and I want to show only discussions where the field called :disabled == false.

Unfortunately, this search:

```
Discussion.search "handy", :conditions => { :disabled => false }
```

always returns an empty array, no matter what.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have an attribute `disabled` defined in your `define_index` block:

```
define_index do
  indexes [subject, body], :as => :text
  indexes replies.body, :as => :reply_text

  has disabled

  set_property :delta => true
end
```

Once you've done this, stop Sphinx, re-index, and restart, and hopefully it should work.